# What's the meaning of "Is it now?"

Tags: american-english, informal-language

Can anyone explain the meaning of "Is it now" to me? I googled this phrase, but I couldn't find the answer out...I heard this from a TV show:

> Maggie: Mail's here, telephone bill, letter from your mother, "Simone's of Siyasi Sexy Sleepwear"
>   Jason: Mmmm. Wonder how we got this.
>   Maggie: Mmm. I don't know. Could it be because it's addressed to a Doctor Jason Seaver?
>   Jason: **Is it now**. You know I've been getting this darn junk mail ever since I sent away for "Slim Whitman's Greatest Hits".

Source: [*Growing Pains* script](https://www.myfitnesspal.com/blog/Joshua0812/view/growing-pains-110-dirt-bike-169500)

Answer (score 3):

I see it as rhetorical question, and could be punctuated as

> Is it, now?

The question is essentially, *is it?*, or *is that true?*, but no answer is expected. In this case, I believe it expresses mild surprise or disbelief with a coy feeling. In other words, he might be pretending to be surprised, but in reality, he knows he ordered the catalog.

In other cases, it could be a genuine expression of surprise.

Comment: In NOAD, meaning #4 for _now_ reads: **used at the end of an ironic question echoing a previous statement**: _“Mom says for you to give me some of your stamps.” “Does she now?”_ I think you've correctly identified the meaning, but I think the comma is typically omitted.